# c# makefile on windows

Tags: c#, makefile

What do I need to install/configure to run the following makefile on windows 7:

```
MONO = mono
MONOC = gmcs
MONOCFLAGS = -optimize -reference:${PARSERREF}
GPLEX = ${MONO} gplex.exe
GPPG = ${MONO} gppg.exe
PARSERREF = bin/ShiftReduceParser.dll
CSFILES = Absyn.cs Parser.cs Printer.cs Scanner.cs Test.cs VisitSkeleton.cs AbstractVisitSkeleton.cs
all: test

clean:
rm -f test.pdf test

distclean: clean
rm -f ${CSFILES}
rm -f test.l test.y test.tex
rm -f Makefile

test: Parser.cs Scanner.cs
@echo "Compiling test..."
${MONOC} ${MONOCFLAGS} -out:bin/test.exe ${CSFILES}

Scanner.cs: test.l
${GPLEX} /out:$@ test.l

Parser.cs: test.y
${GPPG} /gplex test.y > $@
```

I have always used Visual Studio, however, this time, this is generated by BNFC (Parser generator). I don't see the csc.exe (CSharp compiler) in this makefile. Can someone please explain this to me?

Note: I have got gplex.exe and gppg.exe and I have .NET installed on my machine.

Comment: This make file is for Mono (which explains all of the uses of *Mono* in names like `$(MONO)` and `$(MONOCFLAGS)`). So the compiler isn't csc.exe, and you need to either install Mono or change things to use  VS instead.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, so I am going to install mono on Windows and this should then work fine?

Comment: I have installed Mono, now I have this Makefile. How do I execute the makefile? In mac, I can just say make

Comment: @2D3D4D: It's a makefile, you'll need to have GNU make installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install GNU make for Windows

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Afterwards you open cmd.exe and cd to the directory where the makefile is in. 
Then you type make and press enter, or `make test` in this case.